# How to know if color "touch" another color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, colors

I'm trying to create something that if I have a UIView with background of yellow, and this view is moving on the screen, and somewhere placed another UIView with background of red. How can I know if the yellow color touch the red color? - which mean's that the first view touches the another view.

Comment: You can use the `CGRectIntersectsRect` function, with the views' frames to check for intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the animation you will have to periodically check for intersection like @AMI289 has said. e.g.

```
- (void)animate {
    // Use an NSTimer to check for intersection 10 times per second
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkForCollision) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        // Do the animation
    } completion:^(BOOL complete) {
        // Tell timer to stop calling checkForCollision
        [timer invalidate];
    }];
}


- (void)checkForCollision {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect([viewOne.layer.presentationLayer frame], [viewTwo.layer.presentationLayer frame])) {
        // Handle collision
    }
}
```

It is important to get the presentation layer of the views that are being animated otherwise you will not detect incremental changes to the views' positions on the screen. You also need to invalidate the timer once you are done with it otherwise your `checkForCollision` method will continue to run indefinitely.